# My command prompt terminal won't change?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, iterm

Mac OSX Maverick: Using iTerm2

```
nano .zsh
```

Inserted `export PS1=" % "`

**Control + o**

```
File Name to Write: .zsh
```

**Control + x**

Restarted iTerm. And it still goes back to what I had before. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, `.zsh` is not a file used by any shell, not even `zsh`. You probably want `.zshrc` if you're using `zsh`. If you're using Mac's default of `bash`, you want `.bashrc` instead.